# Is it possible to get a resolution greater than 1920x1200 on openbsd in qemu ( virt-manager)?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, openbsd

How to increase screen resolution in openbsd if it possible? It is necessary to have a resolution such as 2k or 4k.

Tried virtio, qxl there is even smaller than in VGA, checked the maximum resolution with xrandr.

When I try to change the resolution to a custom one, I get the error xrandr : Configure crtc 0 failed

Comment: pretty sure I've seen X.org + QXL do higher resolutions. Have you tried manually adding a new mode using `xrandr`?

Comment: Also, I know this loses convenience and performance, but assuming you're not running OpenBSD for 3D acceleration reasons… what about simply using X via virtual network, or even XPra (don't know the state of Xpra on OpenBSD)

Comment: I added that information to the question, seems relevant :)

Comment: in qxl mode max resolution is 1280x768

Comment: Only in vga mode resolution is 1920x1200